# Eliminate duplicate rows from queryset

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

currently my model contain following data,

```
--------------------------
| id | playlist_name     |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1st               |
--------------------------
| 2  | hello1            |
--------------------------
| 3  | hello1            |
--------------------------
| 4  | gfh               |
--------------------------
| 5  | gfh               |
--------------------------
| 6  | ertr              |
--------------------------
| 7  | dg                |
--------------------------
```

I want to get result without duplicate playlist_name, somewhat like below result

```
--------------------------
| id | playlist_name     |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1st               |
--------------------------
| 2  | hello1            |
--------------------------
| 4  | gfh               |
--------------------------
| 6  | ertr              |
--------------------------
| 7  | dg                |
--------------------------
```

How to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `distinct('playlist_name')` for this purpose. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Comment: raise NotSupportedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysongs = playlist.objects.filter(profiles_id=user_id.id).order_by('playlist_name').values('playlist_name').distinct()

since i used mysql, this was solution for me. i am new to stack overflow i dont know why my question got downvoted.